How do I change the separator of the data table with Vuetify 3?
I'm studying Vue and Vuetify 3, and I want to style the data table, but I'm not able to achieve this.
I want to figure out how to change the color or background of the separators of the table content, and how to change the background of the table header.
Thank you!
https://codepen.io/Vinicius-Ribeiro-the-typescripter/pen/QWeWXoG
<v-data-table

  :headers="headers"

  :items="items"

  :items-per-page="3" 

  :pagination.sync="pagination"

  class="elevation-0 ma-0"

  style="max-height: 400px; overflow-y: auto;"

></v-data-table>


Use standard CSS to target the inner elements of the table.  You need to set border-bottom for td and th, and background-color for thead.  If it isn't working for you, please show your attempt.

It also does no good to provide a non-working codepen.  You need to add the Vue and Vuetify libraries to it, or easier would be to just use Vuetify's playground with Vue and Vuetify already included.

Somethig like this => vuetify_playground_example, if I understand correctly.

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  const headers = [
    { title: 'Nome', value: 'name' },

    { title: 'Espécies', value: 'species' },

    { title: 'Dieta', value: 'diet' },

    { title: 'Habitat', value: 'habitat' },
  ]

  const items = [
    {
      name: 'African Elephant',

      species: 'Loxodonta africana',

      diet: 'Herbivore',

      habitat: 'Savanna, Forests',
    },

    {
      name: 'Bengal Tiger',

      species: 'Panthera tigris tigris',

      diet: 'Carnivore',

      habitat: 'Tropical Rainforest',
    },

    {
      name: 'Giant Panda',

      species: 'Ailuropoda melanoleuca',

      diet: 'Herbivore',

      habitat: 'Temperate Broadleaf Forest',
    },
  ]

  const pagination = ref({
    page: 1,

    rowsPerPage: 2,
  })
</script>

<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="items"
      :items-per-page="3"
      :pagination.sync="pagination"
      class="myTable elevation-0 ma-0"
      style="max-height: 400px; overflow-y: auto"
    ></v-data-table>
  </v-container>
</template>

<style scoped>
  :deep(.myTable thead) {
    background-color: teal;
  }

  :deep(.v-theme--light) {
    --v-border-color: 198, 159;
  }

  :deep(.myTable .v-table__wrapper) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(198, 159, 0);
  }
</style>



